# Elegant jQuery replace on mutiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using .replace() with jQuery to remove different strings from an img URL:

```
src = src.replace("/_w", "");
src = src.replace("_jpg", "");
src = src.replace("_jpeg", "");                 
src = src.replace("_png", "");                  
src = src.replace("_gif", "");
```

As you can see its pretty primative and not very clever, is there anyway I can replace this with something a little more elegant.

Essentially the url will always be 1 of the following:

```
http://local.com/images/_w/image_jpg.jpg
http://local.com/images/_w/image_jpeg.jpeg
http://local.com/images/_w/image_png.png
```

Is there anyway I can write a .replace() to remove the /_w/ then remove all characters between the last '.' in the URL and the last underscore?

Answer (score 2):

not tested - but I think this should do it

`src = src.replace(/\/_w|_jpg|_png|_gif/g,'')`

or better still...

`src = src.replace(/\/_w(.+?)_(jpg|png|gif)\./,"$1.")`

which matches /w, then stores all characters up to _gif or _jpg etc... then replaces everything captured with what was stored (followed by a dot).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend.

If it's really safe to replace *everything* between `/_w` and `.` every time you can use:

```
  src = src.replace(/\/_w[^.]*/,'');
```

If you become familiar with the basics of regex it will save you time on countless problems.  It's an incredibly versatile tool.

[A good reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

[A Regex tester](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: hahaha I don't know if I would agree with that but none the less I still use them

Comment: Don't be stingy with your friendship :)